# WPF TreeView Binding do not adds elements

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, datatemplate

I am trying to create TreeView with checkbox, image and some other information hidden from UI.
XAML code:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding T1}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZ" Content="{Binding name}" IsChecked="{Binding box}" Foreground="{Binding color}" Unchecked="CheckBoxZ_Updated" Checked="CheckBoxZ_Updated"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding image}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

C# code:

```
namespace App
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class TS : TreeViewItem
        {
            public string color { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public bool box { get; set; }
            public string path { get; set; }
            public string source { get; set; }
            public int operation { get; set; }
            public ImageSource image { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<TS> Items { get; set; }
            public TS()
            {
                this.Items = new ObservableCollection<TS>();
            }
        }
    public TS T1, T2;
    public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            T1 = new TS() { color = "Green", name = "folder", box = true, path = "C:\\folder", source = "D:\\folder", operation = 0, image = X.ToImageSource(System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("D:\\folder\\file.txt")) };
            T2 = new TS() { color = "Green", name = "file.txt", box = true, path = "C:\\folder\\file.txt", source = "D:\\folder\\file.txt", operation = 2, image = X.ToImageSource(System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("D:\\folder\\file.txt")) };
            T1.Items.Add(T2);
            MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(T1.Items.Count.ToString() + " " + T2.Items.Count.ToString(), "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.None);
        }
    public static ImageSource ToImageSource(Icon icon)
        {
            ImageSource imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                icon.Handle,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            return imageSource;
        }
}
```

Items are successfully added to variable but do not displaying. App started with no errors. I have no variants with this fault. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. WPF can only bind to *properties* - it won't bind to your `T1` *field*.
2. You are trying to bind `TreeView.ItemsSource` to `T1`.  This expects an `IEnumerable`.  You should bind to something like an `ObservableCollection<TS>`
3. You are using a `DataTemplate`.  As each item can have children itself, you should be using `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and binding its `ItemsSource` to the `Items` property on `TS`.

As an aside, I can see no reason why `TS` should inherit `TreeViewItem`.

I'd suggest following one of the many tutorials out there that would walk you through doing this, such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode).

Comment: Thanks for response. 1: I am using the same algorithm in listbox with checkboxes and it works. 2. I am try this just now and problem is not resolved. 3. I'll try.

Comment: *  sorry, listbox uses ObservableCollection<T>.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemsSource` should bind an `ObservableCollection` or some ItemsCollection (`Items` in your case).

I don't understand how you designed your classes. The rough pattern should be as follows:

```
public class TS: TreeViewItem{}
public class TSCollection: ObservableCollection<TS> {}
```

And your `MainWindow` should be something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
TS T1 = new TS(){Name="folder", Color="Green"};
TS T2= new TS(){Name="folder1", Color="Blue"};
TSColletion collection = new TSCollection();
collection.Add(T1,T2);
}
```

And you xaml should then have `collection` as `ItemsSource`
}

Comment: And how to add subitems?

Comment: I understand you need ObservableCollection within your TreeViewItem to have Children, but my point it `ItemsSource` should always bind to a collection of Items and not a single Item